# How can I get posts with specific tags using Prisma

Tags: database, many-to-many, relationship, prisma

I want to get data from Prisma with findmany method with selected tags.

Here are Prisma schema for post and tag.

```
model Post {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  tag         Tag[]
  ...
}
```

```
model Tag {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  Post      Post[]
  ...
}
```

And I tried to run this code to find posts include every tags that I selected (id 12 and 13). Weird thing is it returns empty.

```
const posts = await client.post.findMany({
   where: {
      tag: {
         some: {
            // lets say to find tags id : [12,13]
            AND: [{id: { in: 12 }},{id: { in: 13 }}]
            },
         },
      select: {
         id: true,
         tag: true,
      }
   }
)
```

When I tried to find just one id with `AND: [{id: { in: 12 }}]` it return right posts that include tag with id 12.